# Error while verifying token TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined firebase nodejs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So far everything has been working well but after adding firebase user auth to my app, my application starts misbehaving..

Here's my auth.js code

```
const { admin, db } = require('./admin');

module.exports = (request, response, next) => {
let idToken = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjIzNzA1ZmNmY2NjMTg4Njg2ZjhhZjkyYWJiZjAxYzRmMjZiZDVlODMiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vdG9kby0zNjVlYSIsImF1ZCI6InRvZG8tMzY1ZWEiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE2MDIzNDQyNDUsInVzZXJfaWQiOiJIeGRNcklxeVhQYlpaaWxEQ0NQaW9iNm15WngyIiwic3ViIjoiSHhkTXJJcXlYUGJaWmlsRENDUGlvYjZteVp4MiIsImlhdCI6MTYwMjM0NDI0NSwiZXhwIjoxNjAyMzQ3ODQ1LCJlbWFpbCI6InNhbXVlbG9ub2phOTcwQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjpmYWxzZSwiZmlyZWJhc2UiOnsiaWRlbnRpdGllcyI6eyJlbWFpbCI6WyJzYW11ZWxvbm9qYTk3MEBnbWFpbC5jb20iXX0sInNpZ25faW5fcHJvdmlkZXIiOiJwYXNzd29yZCJ9fQ.mOmV_V69IfCbQuf_QBiNgCsXCwlU4OTkT8fDVp6lkxtaBM8ZfOG55ymRikKJZ6J7z4siyT4sV89p4Ke0LFTX3KcmtkWNVQ0ERpWBvIi8hK2aqO53HbfUUo278tCGZAChx-xC_Drphz7xg8VJAqUm-rxBumqOBSukgivLXJLkBcvW87cNI2JPBmQr_DCL1FVWTYq9cQ9clVoSJDvbAaGZfay9nH5fuLXNs7m0CnFasqRerUoJ41Ro8kelfBMrzsXMp9bwevJNSrgBkjTyN7x5IURdVD8Ln4A6rIIxEJG-xmCmKHluFv3z_hlMEeFDGopQjGTJjeoYWtvh1gmRBnEcjw";
admin
    .auth()
    .verifyIdToken(idToken)
    .then((decodedToken) => {
        request.user = decodedToken;
        return db.collection('users').where('userId', '==', 
request.user.uid).limit(1).get();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        request.user.username = data.docs[0].data().username;
        request.user.imageUrl = data.docs[0].data().imageUrl;
        return next();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Error while verifying token', err);
        return response.status(403).json(err);
    });
};
```

Got the token id from one of the account i added to firebase but i keep getting error on console:
">  Error while verifying token TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

also whenever i try to send GET request, i get only {} printed out

Answer (score 0):

The error is suggesting that your query returned no documents.  You should check to see if the `data` (a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) object) contains any documents at all before trying to access them in the `docs` array.

I'll rename it to `qs` and show a more idiomatic way to use it:

```
    .then((qs) => {
        if (!qs.empty) {
            const data = qs.docs[0].data()
            request.user.username = data.username;
            request.user.imageUrl = data.imageUrl;
            return next();
        }
        else {
            // decide what you want to do if there are no documents
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank !
I got it working.

```
module.exports = (request, response, next) => {
let idToken;
if (request.headers.authorization && request.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
    idToken = request.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
} else {
    console.error('No token found');
    return response.status(403).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' });
}
// idToken comes from the client app
admin
admin
    .auth()
    .verifyIdToken(idToken)
    .then((decodedToken) => {
        request.user = decodedToken;
        return Promise.resolve(db.collection('users').limit(1).get());
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        request.user.username = data.docs[0].data().username;
        request.user.imageUrl = data.docs[0].data().imageUrl;
        return next();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Error while verifying token', err);
        return response.status(403).json(err);
    });
};
```